# How about having a SingletonModel in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm, singleton

I'm making a very simple website in Django. On one of the pages there is a vertical ticker box. I need to give the client a way to edit the contents of the ticker box as an `HTMLField`.

The first way that came to mind was to make a model `Ticker` which will have only one instance. Then I thought, instead of making sure manually that only one instance exists, perhaps there is (or there should be) something like a `SingletonModel` class in Django, which is like a normal model, except it makes sure no more than one instance gets created?

Or perhaps I should be solving my problem in a different way?

Answer (score 11):

Try [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo), it works in django 1.5 + for sure, [django-singletons](https://github.com/tttallis/django-singletons) doesn't work with 1.5 + because it uses a deprecated feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [django_singletons](https://github.com/tttallis/django-singletons). It has a built in admin support.

Answer (score 2):

I think having a "singleton" model is ugly; it's dumb use of the relational database and it's bad UI, because the admin UI is built around working with lists of objects.

Instead I prefer to use a generic solution like [django-chunks](http://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks) or [django-flatblocks](http://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks) for this.

Comment: That's indeed better for text but what about chunks that relate to other models? If for example, you want to list specific projects on the homepage - you're left with 3 options: a) a checkbox on the Project model (project.display_on_homepage) OR b) an Homepage singleton OR c) set up feincms or similar CMS and add a content type for it.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your save method so that every time a Ticker object gets saved it overwrites the existing one (if one exists).

Comment: Possible, but then I would also want a few other things, such as not having a "Add another one" button in the admin, and then we might as well make a `SingletonModel` for all of this.

Answer (score 1):

A model with only one instance, a singleton, is sometime useful for things like global settings that you want to edit from the admin instead of having them in Django settings.py.

There are several third party applications that helps implementing singleton models and improve the admin interface for instance, [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo), [django-singleton-admin](https://github.com/RacingTadpole/django-singleton-admin), [django-singletons](https://github.com/tttallis/django-singletons).