# Django admin - Keep updating a model and do not create more than one

Tags: django, django-admin

Im not sure how to put this title.
But what I need is a simple model that I can just update everytime. Lets say I have a Settings model ,and these settings I just want to update or change every now and again. So there is no need to add another object to that model.

Is there suck a field or type of admin-model that I can use?

I could otherwise just keep updating the same object, but I do not want the user to be able to just "Add Setting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in admin you can specify various permissions. to remove the "add" functionality:

`class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request): return False`

make sure you create your first and only settings object when you deploy the application.

here is a discussion about singleton models in django: [How about having a SingletonModel in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273258/how-about-having-a-singletonmodel-in-django)

Comment: It would be nice if they built something like this in :-)

Comment: I do not understand. this solution does not help?

Comment: It does yes, But I mean If Django built something in like this.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to another related discussion. maybe your settings should be stored not in the database but somewhere else?