# Allow only one instance of a model in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to control some configuration settings for my project using a database model. For example:

```
class JuicerBaseSettings(models.Model):
    max_rpm = model.IntegerField(default=10)
    min_rpm = model.IntegerField(default=0)
```

There should only be one instance of this model:

```
juicer_base = JuicerBaseSettings()
juicer_base.save()
```

Of course, if someone accidentally creates a new instances, it's not the end of the world. I could just do `JuicerBaseSettings.objects.all().first()`. However, is there a way to lock it down such that it's impossible to create more than 1 instance?

I found two related questions on SO. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273258/how-about-having-a-singletonmodel-in-django) suggests using 3rd party apps like `django-singletons`, which doesn't seem to be actively maintained (last update to the git repo is 5 years ago). [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888159/django-models-only-permit-one-entry-in-a-model) suggests using a combination of either permissions or `OneToOneField`. Both answers are from 2010-2011.

Given that Django has changed a lot since then, are there any standard ways to solve this problem? Or should I just use `.first()` and accept that there may be duplicates?

Comment: ... or you could do `.get(pk=1)` instead...

Comment: this shouldn't be in the database at all

Comment: @e4c5 reasonable, but in small projects I always face with site settings like that, which allow to client change in admin, something like phone number or other related to project stuff. Maybe you point to better way

Comment: @e4c5 Could you recommend an alternative? One benefit of having this in the database means I can expose it via a REST API.

Comment: [`django-constance`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) does exactly what you need

Comment: Django-constance seems to leave the settings in the settings.py file.
It would be nice if we could allow an admin user to use a form to update any changes. is this possible?
I have tried django-solo but updating the model causes errors.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can override `save` method to control a number of instances:

```
class JuicerBaseSettings(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk and JuicerBaseSettings.objects.exists():
        # if you'll not check for self.pk 
        # then error will also be raised in the update of exists model
            raise ValidationError('There is can be only one JuicerBaseSettings instance')
        return super(JuicerBaseSettings, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 12):

Either you can override save and create a class function `JuicerBaseSettings.object()`

```
class JuicerBaseSettings(models.Model):

    @classmethod
    def object(cls):
        return cls._default_manager.all().first() # Since only one item

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = self.id = 1
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

============= OR =============

Simply, Use `django_solo`.

https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo

`Snippet Courtsy: django-solo-documentation.`

```
# models.py


from django.db import models
from solo.models import SingletonModel

class SiteConfiguration(SingletonModel):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Site Name')
    maintenance_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Site Configuration"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Site Configuration"
```

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from solo.admin import SingletonModelAdmin
from config.models import SiteConfiguration

admin.site.register(SiteConfiguration, SingletonModelAdmin)

# There is only one item in the table, you can get it this way:
from .models import SiteConfiguration
config = SiteConfiguration.objects.get()

# get_solo will create the item if it does not already exist
config = SiteConfiguration.get_solo()
```

Comment: for django_solo that do it in clean way

Answer (score 9):

If your model is used in django-admin only, you additionally can set dynamic *add permission* for your model:

```
# some imports here
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import models

@admin.register(models.ExampleModel)
class ExampleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    # some code...

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        # check if generally has add permission
        retVal = super().has_add_permission(request)
        # set add permission to False, if object already exists
        if retVal and models.ExampleModel.objects.exists():
            retVal = False
        return retVal
```

Comment: This is great and efficient. However, the super needs the class name and self as argument (super(ExampleModelAdmin, self).has_add_permission(request)

Comment: @Peterpanx not with Python 3

Answer (score 4):

i am not an expert but i guess you can overwrite the model's save() method so that it will check if there has already been a instance , if so the save() method will just return , otherwise it will call the super().save()

Comment: Yes, I agree this is the best answer. Overwrite save() and check if it has a pk. If it does, then it is an update and that is fine, if not... Then check the dB to see if id=1 exists and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pre_save signal

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=JuicerBaseSettings)
def check_no_conflicting_juicer(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # If another JuicerBaseSettings object exists a ValidationError will be raised
    if JuicerBaseSettings.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk).exists():
        raise ValidationError('A JuiceBaseSettings object already exists')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but if you want  to ensure  that only one instance of an object is created, an alternative solution to modifying a models save() function would be to always specify an ID of 1 when creating an instance - that way, if an instance already exists, an integrity error will be raised.
e.g.

```
JuicerBaseSettings.objects.create(id=1)
```

instead of:

```
JuicerBaseSettings.objects.create()
```

It's not as clean of a solution as modifying the save  function but it still does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this in my admin so that I won't ever go to original `add_new` view at all unless there's no object already present:

```py
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    obj = MyModel.objects.all().first()
    if obj:
        return self.change_view(request, object_id=str(obj.id) if obj else None)
    else:
        return super(type(self), self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    return self.add_view(request)
```

**Works only when saving from admin**