# Update a Model value in database: django

Tags: django, django-models, models, django-database

I've created a model in Django which is as follows:

```
class LatestSavedKeyPassword(models.Model):

    key_password = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        help_text="<b><a>System Generated, Do Not Alter</a></b>")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key_password
```

Now I want to save value `passwordval` to the field.

I want to save value in this model through `admin.py`

```
def save_key_password(self, request):
    LatestSavedKeyPassword.objects.update(
            cert_password=password)
```

Can I save the value like this?

Also I want that when I use this model again, then the previous value gets updated and don't want a new entry to be created.

How to do it?

I'm using Django 2.0 and python 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only one instance of a model in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412968/allow-only-one-instance-of-a-model-in-django)

Comment: LatestSavedKeyPassword.objects.filter(pk=some_pk).update(
            cert_password=password) I think you want to update specific instance not all instances. Can you describe your situation more clearly, please ?